# Laravel Jetstream Inertia error on API Tokens page Could not parse DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

When i install Jetstream with Inertia stack  at laravel 8 and try to access the API Tokens page, get the error:

```
Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException
Could not parse 'Thu 24 Jun 16:46:15 2021': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Thu 24 Jun 16:46:15 2021) at position 13 (:): Unexpected character
```

With PostgresSQL Database

Happens with a fresh laravel install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: The problem occurs on a new laravel project with Jetstream, i am not even creating a route